# Открытие новой вкладки браузера Selenium WebDeiver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Требуется открыть в браузере две страницы. К примеру, программа открывает YouTube.com, после чего открывает новую вкладку и переходит на vk.com
Не могу найти нигде метод, благодаря которому можно будет открыть новую вкладку и ввести туда URL.
Неужели нет такого способа? Везде описывают только способ открытия ссылки на странице в новой вкладке, но что делать, если я просто хочу открыть новую вкладку и перейти по адресу, который я напишу сам?

---

Никакие способы открытия вкладки мне не помогли, кроме этого:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41037608

Только через Джаву удалось открыть новую вкладку!

Comment: [Тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19441842/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 Я написал такой код:
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');

Но не происходит вообще ничего! Не передаются клавиши в Chrome!

Comment: Вы пробовали код, что по ссылке из моего коммента?

Comment: Пробовал, горячие клавиши вообще не отправляются в Chrome

Answer (score 2):

В официальной [документации](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/) к Selenium приводится такой пример:

```
// Открытие новой вкладки
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

// Открытие новго окна
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Попробуйте данный вариант

Comment: отличный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium не умеет открывать новые вкладки и окна. Но, в то же время, может ими управлять. Все способы, с помощью которых можно это сделать, по сути, хаки. Либо через JS, либо через хоткеи браузера. Вот примеры (ссылку взял в комментах к вопросу) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558909/9063000

Если хотите делать по-правильному, то инициализируйте два драйвера просто.

Comment: У меня браузер вообще не реагирует на то, что я ему посылаю хоткеи! Написал это:
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');
Chrome просто проигнорировал мой хоткей...
Я в растерянности, в этой теме недавно, поэтому вообще не понимаю как в такой ситуации действовать